# Weblogic maximum thread error

Tags: jakarta-ee, weblogic12c

My weblogic server gives error in eclipse console after clicking on items frequently.

Error: There are: 5 active sockets, but the maximum number of socket reader threads allowed by the configuration is: 4. The configuration may need altered.

I tried to resolve it by

1. Altering config.xml putting following lines in server tag.

   <self-tuning-thread-pool-size-min> 50 </self-tuning-thread-pool-size-min>

   <self-tuning-thread-pool-size-max 150</self-tuning-thread-pool-size-max>
2. Setting options to JAVA_OPTIONS in startweblogic.cmd

   -Dweblogic.threadpool.MinPoolSize=50 -Dweblogic.threadpool.MaxPoolSize=50

But none resolved the issue. Please help me.

Weblogic Version I am using in 12.1.1 with JDK 7.1_51.

Eclipse IDE : Juno

Answer (score 0):

Added the directory in wich the dll lives to the PATH in the startupscript  ...\weblogic\domain1\bin\startWebLogic.cmd:

set WL_HOME=C:\java\weblogic\12.1.1\wlserver
set PATH=%WL_HOME%\server\native\win\x64;%PATH%A